# Origin of word dog

Tags: etymology

Many years ago I read that the word dog entered the English language when some Dutch traders in late Medieval times brought "dogges" to sell in England.  I do not remember the source.  Has anyone else read or heard of this?

Comment: There should be some more information here ---> https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418717/origin-of-word-dog